# Qual é a tradução para o inglês da frase 'da mesma forma que antes'?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

Qual é a tradução para o inglês da frase 'da mesma forma que antes'? Eu achei que a melhor tradução (para o inglês) dessa frase seria 'in the same way as before', porém me disseram que está errado e que isso não faz sentido no inglês. Uma tradução melhor seria 'in the same fashion as before' ou 'likewise as before'?

Comment: Se "(in) the same way as before" estiver errado, os anglófonos também devem cometer esse errado, porque já o ouvi.

Comment: Também não vejo problema com sua tradução, mas para ter certeza seria importante ter o/um contexto em que a frase seria usada.

Comment: Eu falava com o Guilherme, @Schilive, também acho essa uma boa tradução, mas em um dado contexto pode haver outras opções. E, Guilherme, "likewise as before" soa estranho para meus ouvidos.

Comment: @stafusa e se o contexto for um texto matemático (de um artigo), daí eu gostaria de fazer algo que já foi feito e para isso eu gostaria de escrever 'da mesma forma que antes podemos concluir tal coisa'. Nesse caso, 'in the same way as before' continua sendo a melhor tradução?

Comment: @stafusa aliás, 'in the same fashion as before' também estaria correto?

Comment: Eu diria que as duas opções são boas. No contexto de um paper, você pode preferir ser mais específico (se já não estiver sendo no restante da frase), e outras opções talvez sejam "following the same steps/procedure/reasoning as before" ou, se houver pequenas diferenças e a referência for clara, simplesmente "analogously".

Comment: There is not necessarily and "in" at all. Ele fez a comida da mesma forma que antes. He made the food *the same way* as before. See? No "in". "likewise as before" is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Da mesma forma que antes" é a resposta a uma pergunta?  Ou é a continuação de uma frase?
Dependendo do verbo e sujeito da oração, são várias as maneiras possíveis de se dizer "da mesma forma que antes".  Lembre-se, contexto é tudo:

- "Vamos fazer diferente dessa vez?"  No, let's do it just as we did before.
- "Tua mãe mudou de opinião?"  No, she still thinks the same way.
- "Devo mandar a resposta por e-mail?" Do it exactly as you did before.
- "O custo de vida, como está?"  Just as it was before.
- "Como estão as coisas em Lisboa?"  Exactly the same. No change at all.

EDIT

"da mesma forma que antes, podemos concluir que..." –  **"Just as we've done before, we can reason that..."**

Comment: É a continuação de uma frase. Não é pergunta.Como por exemplo "...da mesma forma que antes, podemos concluir que..."

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma mais coloquial, que se escuta com mais frequencia seria:
"Just like before"