# Existe algum paralelo para "servidor público" no inglês?

Tags: tradução, termos-em-inglês

No Brasil, [servidor público](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_p%C3%BAblico) (alternativamente, funcionário público) é, essencialmente, aquele empregado diretamente pelo governo, seja pela União, por uma Unidade Federativa ou por um município.

Vários outros aspectos os diferenciam da classe normal de trabalhadores, por exemplo:

- O ingresso na carreira pública requer, via de regra, ser aprovado em um concurso.
- Há crimes que são específicos de servidor público. Vide *Código Penal: Capítulo I – Dos Crimes Praticados por Funcionário Público contra a
  Administração em Geral*.
- Eles têm estabilidade no emprego, o que significa que só podem ser demitidos por infrações específicas e mediante processo administrativo com direito a ampla defesa.

**Existe algum termo em inglês que dê conta de comunicar, ainda que imperfeitamente, o conceito de servidor público**, ou só nos resta explicar pormenorizadamente as suas características?

Comment: "Existe algum termo em inglês que dê conta de comunicar, ainda que imperfeitamente, o conceito de servidor público." Acho muito estranho dizer isso. Todos paises tem funcionário público. Até os que tem governos autoritários. Senão como lidar com a população?

Comment: Aqui fazemos tradução ao português, mas não ao inglês....

Comment: "Todos paises tem funcionário público." Entendo, porém não garantidamente com as mesmas características, como as que elenquei.

Comment: "Aqui fazemos tradução ao português, mas não ao inglês." Oh, perdão, vendo outras questões abertas aqui que solicitam essa tradução (p. ex. https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8495/qual-é-a-tradução-para-o-inglês-da-frase-da-mesma-forma-que-antes) achei que fosse válido.

Comment: Stafusa, Lambie está certo, que não se faz tradução do português ao inglês aqui no site?

Comment: @Schilive Boa pergunta. Por um lado somos oficialmente _mais_ restritivos que a Lambie afirma: segundo nosso [help](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), toda tradução é off topic: "We are not a translation service [...] please don't ask us to translate a text **to or from** another language."; por outro lado temos as tags tradução[-inglês], e elas inclusive estão no top 10 das [tags](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/tags), portanto, na prática, temos respondido a esse tipo de pergunta. Eu não deletaria questões de tradução antes de uma boa discussão no meta sobre o assunto.

Comment: No otros sites, como o francês, só se tolera tradução para o francês, nas respostas. São vocês que decidem. Para mim, dá igual.

Answer (score 2):

Um ótimo termo é **civil servant** ou **public servant**. De [Wikipedia: Civil service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_service):

> The civil service is a collective term for a sector of government composed mainly of career civil servants hired on professional merit rather than appointed or elected, whose institutional tenure typically survives transitions of political leadership. A civil servant, also known as public servant, is a person employed in the public sector by a government department or agency for public sector undertakings. Civil servants work for central and state governments, and answer to the government, not a political party.

Minha tradução para o português:

> O serviço público é um termo coletivo para um setor do governo composto principalmente por servidores públicos de carreira, contratados por mérito profissional em vez de por indicações ou eleições, cujo mandato tipicamente sobrevive às transições das lideranças políticas. Um servidor público, também conhecido como funcionário público, é uma pessoa empregada no setor público por um departamento do governo ou por empreendimentos do setor público. Servidores públicos trabalham para os governos central e estadual, e respondem ao governo, não a um partido político.

Comment: em vez de nomeação or eleições, cujo mandato//public sector undertakings: empreendimentos do/no setor público//

Comment: Obrigado, Lambie, incorporei suas sugestões, exceto a primeira (de indicação para nomeação), já que todo servidor público deve ser nomeado para a posse (esse é o jargão).